# Which relations are partial orders

Tags: relations

I have come across the following question on a practice test:

> Which of the following relations defined on $X = \{1, 2, 3\}$ are partial orders?
>
> $(1) \; \{(1, 1),(2, 2),(3, 3)\}$
>
> $(2) \; \{(1, 2),(2, 1),(2, 2),(3, 3)\}$
>
> $(3) \; \{(1, 1),(2, 1),(2, 2),(1, 3),(3, 3),(3, 1)\}$
>
> $(4) \; \{(1, 1),(2, 2),(1, 3),(1, 2)\}$
>
> $(5) \; \{(1, 1),(2, 2),(3, 3),(1, 3),(1, 2)\}$

My answer would be that $1$ and $5$ are partial orders on $X$. This is due to $(2)$ and $(3)$ having the symmetric property and $(4)$ not being reflexive.

Can anyone validate my answer?

Comment: Your argument for $(2)$ and $(3)$ doesn't work, because a relation can be both symmetric and antisymmetric at the same time.

Comment: @mrp Thanks, after more consideration: what if I say that they are not partial orders because $(2)$ isn't reflexive and $(3)$ is not antisymmetric.

Comment: Yes, that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your solution. Good work supplying your working.

(I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'm submitting this as an answer)